# How many levels are in Celeste Classic (PICO-8)?

Tags: celeste

In Chapter 3 (Celestial Resort), there is a hidden playable version of the [original Celeste prototype](https://mattmakesgames.itch.io/celesteclassic) on a PICO-8 computer.

The game is surprisingly lengthy. I expected it to end at 2500m (screen 25), but it just seems to keep getting harder.

How many levels are in Celeste Classic?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to a TAS video by Justin Jaffray, Celeste Classic goes up to 3000 m, plus the summit.

Completing Celeste Classic will unlock the *Real Gamer* achievement on PS4, Xbox One, or PC. (The Switch version does not have achievements).

Comment: Having gone back and finished it, I can confirm the summit is just after 3000m. There is no in-game reward for finishing Celeste Classic.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro There's an Achievement in the Xbox One version, at least.

Comment: @tobiasvl Ah, I played on Switch which doesn’t have achievements.

Comment: Stuck on 17. The video shows her running right through spikes (1:08), I don't get it. Is this with some kind of cheat code?

Comment: @devios1 This is a tool assisted run (TAS), it takes  advantage of glitches and extremely precise techniques that a human couldn't do. I would recommend finding a non-TAS video if you need assistance. (for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjenZS4xa3o)

Answer (score 4):

**30 Levels** (3000 meters, 1 level = 100m)

<sub>Source: just completed the minigame myself :)</sub>